# Is it possible to use Ellipsis with RNPickerSelect : react-native-picker-select

Tags: android, react-native, picker, react-native-picker-select

I'm using react-native-picker-select, and I want to customize the picker (color and fontWeight).

So I set `useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}` but if the width value is longer than my picker, there is no ellipsis, and text seems truncated by the left : [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmBkU.png)

On iOS everythings fine : [iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsFXs.png)

Is it possible to make the Android look like iOS with useNativeAndroidPickerStyle to false so I can set the fontWeight to bold?

```
<RNPickerSelect
  placeholder={{}}
  style={form.smallSelect}
  style={{
    inputIOS: {
      ...form.smallInputIOS,
    },
    inputAndroid: {
      ...form.smallInputAndroid,
    },
  }}
  useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
/>


...
  smallInputIOS: {
    color: SkinColors.green,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: normalize(15),
    width: '85%',
    paddingLeft: normalize(12),
    borderRadius: 30,
    height: normalize(30),
  },
  smallInputAndroid: {
    color: SkinColors.green,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: normalize(15),
    width: '100%',
    paddingLeft: normalize(12),
    borderRadius: 30,
    height: normalize(30),
    margin: 0,
    padding: 0,
  },
```

Thank you

Comment: can you try substring like take 40 chars

Comment: @IlanZ93 Have you fixed it?